# Change Mapping of fields of CreateUserWizard control with membership provider asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, membership, login-control

I am using CreateUserWizard Control with membership provider in asp.net 4.0.

In this case user name is stored in 'user name' field in aspnet_Users table.

I want to save 'user name' field in email field of aspnet_Membership table (In my case username is also email);
***In other words I want to  change mapping of these fields.***

How can I do this?

**Note: My Problem is how to change mapping. Above is the only example**

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achive by calling CreateUser method instead of using CreateUserWizard.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="Server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="Server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="PasswordQuestionTextBox" runat="Server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="PasswordAnswerTextBox" runat="Server" />

string username = EmailTextBox.text; // Same as email
string password = PasswordTextBox.text;
string email = EmailTextBox.text;
string passwordQuestion = PasswordQuestionTextBox.text;
string passwordAnswer = PasswordAnswerTextBox.text;
bool isApproved = true;

MembershipCreateStatus status;

MembershipUser membershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved, out status);

if (status != MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
   throw new Exception(status.ToString());
```